how to override sales rule module and a option field to the view file
how to override the sales rule module and an option field to the view file and check the option is enabled or not
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml

You can override files which you needed by preference.
You can try this for override xml file like :
app/code/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml


It's good that you want to contribute frequently, but please leave greetings/signatures out of posts, e.g. "Hey," "Thanks". This is general Stack Exchange policy.
